# Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=2.0.19.1 (.Net 5 )

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net

I am trying to take a .net 4.7 application and port it to .net 5.

In the .net 4.7 application I was using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess to connect to the database without any oracle client installation - and it worked fantastically.

With the .Net 5 application I am now using [Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core/) but when the code hits the class used to interact with the database I get the following :

[image: User-Unhandled-Exception]

My method for installing the package to my project is to just go directly to nuget :

[image: Nuget Installation]

Note that the using statement is as below :

```
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
```

Am I being a bit thick and not doing something I should ? I have tried the following :

- Change the project CPU target to "ALL CPU" - but the project is currently targeting x64 platforms.
- Added and removed the nuget libraries
- Added both the .net core version and .net framework version of the library

Comment: Maybe check your GAC with [Gacutil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/gacutil-exe-gac-tool) tool

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the issue resolved , not in a great way but its working now.

I took the downloaded library from > `C:\Users\<User>\.nuget\packages\oracle.manageddataaccess.core\2.19.101\lib\netstandard2.0\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll`  and then copied it to a folder in my project.

Once there , I removed the nuget package reference and just added a reference directly to the binary itself and - hey presto - all working.